# Apply animation in css3?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, jquery-animate

I just came across `animate.css` yesterday and wanted to apply it to my website.
But the problem was it only worked once, no matter how many times I hovered over the div it stays the same! Maybe I didn't quite grasp the coding technique properly. Here is my code:

```
    window.setTimeout( function(){
   $('#test').removeClass('animated bounce')},
1300);

$(function(){
    $('#test').hover(function(){
            $('#test').addClass('animated bounce');

    });
});
```

**Appreciate all the suggestions !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('#test').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('animated bounce');

}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('animated-bounce');
});
```

or even better

```
  $('#test').hover(function(){
     $(this).addClass('animated-bounce');
  });

  var element = document.getElementById('test');
  element.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", function(){
    $(element).removeClass('animated-bounce');
  }, false);
```

Actually.

Why don't use just do it with css

```
#test:hover{
   animation: animateName ....;
}
```

The problem your having is that when you add the class the animation works but when you hover a second time it doesn't add the class again because it is already there so `CSS` doesn't know when you have hovered it without a change in class name.

[Link to Animation Event DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations#Adding_the_animation_event_listeners)

[AnimationEnd Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dvf5K/)

[CSS :hover Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dvf5K/1/)

Comment: I'm not quite sure why the last 2 methods are better! Because the only one that worked is the first one ^_^. Thanks so much!

Comment: In my case only the first one worked! (maybe the other scripts and codes intervene somehow !)

Comment: I forgot. but `AnimationEnd` needs to be prefixed. i have added demo's at the bottom for both of them